# zend_db_select with a hexadecimal query parameter against a binary column

Tags: pdo, mysqli, zend-db, zend-db-select

How do you represent this query as a Zend_Db_Select?

```
select * from t where id = x'0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661';
```

The database is MySQL, using either PDO or mysqli adapters.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably to use Zend_Db_Expr:

```
$adapter->select()->from('t')->where('id = ?', new Zend_Db_Expr("x'0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661'"));
```